# Screen blink twice every 10 seconds on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, screen

On 12.04 64-bit, about every 5 seconds my screen blinks twice. Even during installation of Ubuntu from CD, this happens during the complete process.

I had no problems with earlier Ubuntu versions (earlier version was 10.04LTS 64-bit)

System specs:

- I7-2600K
- MSI 7681 Motherboard
- 16 GB RAM
- 2 x Nvidia 560 card SLI (only 1 screen on 1 card active during install process)

This flickering is driving me crazy, please help.

Comment: Did you check if it only occurs when using only the laptop battery as source of power? 

That's my case. If I connect the charger the problem finishes. I don't know how to solve it...

Answer (score 0):

Try this to make sure you have the best driver for nvidia cards

Add the PPA for nvidia

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
```

Update software sources

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Download the driver

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Then reboot

This fixes many nvidia issues so may help you

Comment: The original version of drivers did good on my setup. After installing the latest drivers using the above procedure the blinking effect appeared. I'm currently using the 304 version.